# Why is set-o errexit breaking this read/heredoc expression?

Tags: bash

I have been using the pattern below for printing multiline messages to terminal in a bash script.

```
read -d '' message <<- EOF
    this is a 
    mulitline
    message
EOF
echo "$message"
```

This has been working - until a couple of days ago the pattern just stopped working. By stopped working, I mean when bash encountered these heredoc expressions in the script - it just seems to do nothing -  no output.
The only thing that I can think of thats changed in the last few days is that the environment the scripts are run inside is a Ubuntu 14.04 live USB, versus "full" installs.
Then I discovered that when I move the heredoc before the scripts `set -o errexit` statement it started working again. i.e. this doesn't work

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit

read -d '' message <<- EOF
    this is a 
    mulitline
    message
EOF

echo "$message"
```

result: (nothing)
But this *does work*

```
#!/bin/bash

read -d '' message <<- EOF
    this is a 
    mulitline
    message
EOF

echo "$message"
```

result

```
$ sudo ./script.sh 
this is a 
mulitline
message
```

- bash --version - `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`read` returns a non-zero exit status if it doesn't find a delimiter. With the delimiter set to the empty string, it uses the NUL byte as a delimiter, and those usually aren't found in text files.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's `\0`, not empty string.

Comment: @cuonglm, more precisely, when an empty argument is passed to `-d`, then the delimiter is `\0` (a NUL byte). A special case mostly the result of a coding accident (though [the `bash` maintainer won't admit it and explains why it's not documented](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.bash.bugs/24988/focus=24993)).

Comment: "...which is always the case when the delimiter is an empty string." As pointed out by others, it's actually `\0` -- and that doesn't always fail, you can use `read -d ''` to process the output of `find ... -print0`, for example.

Comment: It's [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) in now, in the 5.0 man page at least.

Answer (score 12):

The exit code of the read command is 1 when the end of file (EOF) marker is reached. This will always happen when the delimiter `-d` is null `''` in this special case where the source stream is a heredoc that could not contain a \0.

```
$ read -d '' message <<-_ThisMessageEnds_
>     this is a
>     multi line
>     message
> _ThisMessageEnds_
$ exitval=$?
$ echo "The exit val was $exitval"
The exit val was 1.
```

That the exit value is an error (not 0) makes the script exit could be avoided with a AND/OR construct:

```
read -d '' message <<-_ThisMessageEnds_ || echo "$message"
    this is a
    multi line
    message
_ThisMessageEnds_
```

That will send the message to the console and yet avoid exiting it with `errexit`.

But as we are on this path to reduce, why not use this directly:

```
cat <<-_ThisMessageEnds_
    this is a
    mulitline
    message
_ThisMessageEnds_
```

No read command executed (more speed), no variable needed, no error from the exit code, less code to maintain.

Comment: thanks, good to know about using `||` to prevent the script exit. I ended up taking `errexit` out of the script completely, I have had problems with it not triggering exit when it should - so it seems too tricky to be useful. I have also considered the simpler pattern with `cat <<- EOF message EOF` too . It was just nice to have the message in a variable that could be passed to a function if  necessary

Comment: "No read command executed (more speed)" -> read is a bash-builtin, cat an external program, so I doubt cat is faster (as fork-exec is necessary).

Comment: +1 `||` e.g. `read -d '' -r foo <<EOF || :`...

Answer (score 8):

```
read -d '' message
```

reads stdin until the first unescaped (as you didn't add `-r`) NUL character or the end of the input and stores the data after `$IFS` and backslash character processing into `$message` (without the delimiter).

If no unescaped delimiter is found in the input, `read`'s exit status is non-zero. It only returns 0 (success) if a full, terminated record is read.

It's most useful for dealing with NUL-delimited records like the output of `find -print0` (though you then need a `IFS= read -rd '' record` syntax).

Here, you need to include a NUL delimiter in your here-document for `read` to return successfully. That is however not possible with `bash` which strips NUL characters from here-documents (that's at least better than `yash` that strips everything past the first NUL, or ksh93 which seems to enter an infinite loop when a here-document contains a NUL).

`zsh` is the only shell that can have a NUL in its here documents or store it in its variables or pass NUL characters in arguments to its builtins/functions. In `zsh`, you can do:

```
NUL=$'\0'
IFS= read -d $NUL -r var << EOF
1
2
3$NUL
EOF
```

(`zsh` also understand `read -d ''` as a NUL delimiter like `bash`. `read -d $'\0'` also works in `bash` but that does pass an empty argument to `read` like in `read -d ''` as `bash` doesn't support NUL bytes in its command line).

(note that there's an extra newline character after that `$NUL`)

In `bash`, you can use a different character:

```
ONE=$'\1'
IFS= read -d "$ONE" -r var << EOF
1
2
3$ONE
EOF
```

But you could also do:

```
var=$(cat <<EOF
message
here
EOF
)
```

That will still not allow NUL characters. That's however standard code, so you don't need to rely on the zsh/bash specific `read -d`. Also note that it removes all trailing newline characters, and except in `ksh93` when the `cat` builtin is enabled, that means spawning an extra process and command.

Comment: So, it means `read` return non-zero in this case because of no delimiter found, doesn't it?

Comment: @cuonglm, yes, that's the same as your answer, just expanding on a few things.

Comment: @cuonglm, see also [this recent thread on the bash mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.bash.bugs/24988/focus=24992)

Answer (score 7):

When you use `set -o errexit` and your script breaks, it means there's something wrong.

Here, it's [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html#tag_20_109), which cannot correctly read your input.

In `bash`, when you use `read -d ''`, the [`read` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read) will use the null character `\0` as line terminator. Therefore, when there's no `\0` in your input, `read` will read all the input into the `message` variable and will return a non-zero exit status to indicate there was an error:

```
$ while read -d '' line; do echo "$line"; done < <(printf '1')
```

prints nothing while:

```
$ while read -d '' line; do echo "$line"; done < <(printf '1\0')
1
```

gives you `1`.

`read` will also return non-zero status when it reaches EOF, but that's used for indicating there's no more input to read when you use `read` with a `while` loop, so the `while` loop can be terminated. It's not relevant to your problem.

Comment: thanks, the other answers explained that my  `read` expression, was breaking the script. But thats a good point that read also exits non-zero when used  with a `read`, `while` loop. For that reason I dont think `set -o errexit` is reliable, because sometimes commands need to return non-zero as part of normal program flow

Comment: @the_velour_fog: It's reliable, if you want it's a part of program flow, then use the flow control, like `if read ...`

Comment: The correct description is in searching for a NUL delimiter the EOF was found first. What should read do on finding an EOF: report an error, which it does.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Doesn't the act of using a `while` shield the `exit code` that `read` emits from the `set -o errexit` ?. This is clearly in opposition to what the OP user presented as code and is actually misleading.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, yes, though I understand cuonglm used the while loop for illustration that `read` returns with failure (and exit the loop) upon a not-found delimiter (though I'd agree it probably just adds more confusion).

Comment: In essence, we're all saying the same thing, just more or less clearly, there's not much point arguing any more about it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas No, there is no useful point in discussing it anymore, just that cuonglm required that we asked you. So, you answered.